# Не работает INSERT INTO после первого ввода

Tags: python, sqlite3, insert

```
import sqlite3


db = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
sql = db.cursor()


sql.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id TEXT,
    money INT
) """)
db.commit()

user_id = input('ID: ')
user_money = int(input('money: '))

sql.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = '{user_id}'")
if sql.fetchone() is None:
    sql.execute(f"INSERT INTO users (id, money) VALUES({user_id}, {user_money})")
    db.commit()
else:
    print('Данная запись имеется')

sql.execute("""SELECT * FROM users""")
print(sql.fetchone())
db.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в записи SQL оператора. Строковые значения в операторе нужно брать в каычки. Вот так:

```
sql.execute(f"INSERT INTO users (id, money) VALUES('{user_id}', {user_money})")
```